# How to implement custom fields in database

Tags: mysql, sql, json, database

I need to implement a custom fields in my database so every user can add any fields he wants to his form/entities.

The user should be able to filter or/and sort his data by any custom field.

I want to work with MySQL because the rest of my data is very suitable to SQL. So, unless you have a great idea, SQL will be preferred over NoSQL.

We thought about few solutions:

1. JSON field - Great for dynamic schema. Can be filtered and sorted. The problem is that it is slower then regular columns. 
   Dynamic indexes can solve that but is it too risky to add indexes dynamically.
2. Key-value table - A simple solution but a really slow one. You can't index it properly and the queries are awful.
3. Static placeholder columns - Create N columns and hold a map of each field to its placeholder. - A good solution in terms of performance but it makes the DB not readable and it has limited columns.

Any thoughts how to improve any of the solutions or any idea for a new solution?

Comment: Postgres allows indexes on JSON fields; however, we are not supposed to make software recommendations, so this is merely an observation.

Comment: MySQL as well, but do you recommend to add indexes dynamically? add index is a very heavy action which locks the table as far as I understand

Comment: @GuySegev - That's a question for you to answer.  What is the burden of not indexing?  You say the user should be able to sort or filter by those columns, doing so isn't ever free, but it is cheaper with appropriate indexing.  The problem you're facing is that the `S` in `SQL` is `Structured` and that applies to the data as well as the language.  The idea of dynamic columns that apply to some rows and not others is a description of `unstructured` or `partially structured` data.

Comment: I thought about JSON fields but I'm open to other solutions. This is why I'm asking my question here

Comment: An alternative is an `EAV` table ; `Entity` *(a key to the real row you're adding data to)*, `Attribute` *(a "name" for the column/attribute/field/data that you're adding to that row)*, `Value` *(the, umm, value, that you're adding)*.  Instead of adding columns, you add rows.  But they are also slow when used for filtering or sorting.  I suspect there is no *good* answer, only a `least worst` and that will depend heavily on your data, use cases, application, etc.

Comment: @GuySegev . . . Without getting into a religious war, MySQL 5.7 has indexes on generated columns.  This is not the same as an index on JSON (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html).

Comment: @MatBailie I've edited my question to make it clearer.

Comment: Using a pivot table for the relations maybe? Indexing could be better then. Maybe same as EAV or KV table but better indexed.

Comment: @GuySegev - It was already clear enough.  My comments are not criticisms of your question, they're observations regarding how suitable SQL is *(or is not)* to your use-case.  You *can* make it work, but you're going to have trade-offs to make.  Those trade-offs are related to how many different columns you might have *(i.e. 1000 users each having 5 bespoke columns each is very different to 5 admin users creating 5 columns shared by 1000 other users)*.  They're related to how much data each user has *(i.e. If a user only queries their own 100 rows of data, do you really need an index?)*.  etc..

Comment: If you message me as full a description of actual use case, then I can give my opinion.  But opinion based questions are out of scope for SO, so it would need to be a message/chat.  *(Numbers of users, numbers of bespoke columns, numbers of rows, data types, nature of the queries against this data, etc, etc.  The more background/context the better an opinion I can give.  But you're never going to get "an answer".)*

Comment: I thought about opening a thread of idea here. I find that problem pretty common but without good design pattern.

Comment: We have in our case few admins which will add few columns to a lot of users. Each admin has its own tenant. So users will have fields depending on the account they belong.

Comment: So, is setting up new columns a "set-up-time-only" task, executed only by administrators?

Comment: @NevilleKuyt yes

Answer (score 1):

As many of the commenters have remarked, there is no easy answer to this question. Depending on which trade-offs you're willing to make, I think the JSON solution is neatest - it's "native" to MySQL, so easiest to explain and understand.

However, given that you write that the columns are specified only at set up time, by technically proficient people, you could, of course, have the set-up process include an "alter table" statement to add new columns. Your database access code and all the associated view logic would then need to be configurable too; it's definitely non-trivial.

However...it's a proven solution. Magento and Drupal, for instance, have admin screens for adding attributes to the business entities, which in turn adds columns to the relational database.